# RefineryCMS and adding style to img tag

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, refinerycms

I need to add style to an img tag inside a refineryCMS application it works at first but when i change the image of course that style is delete and we find the default style of the img tag .
so how could I preserve that style even so i change the image?

this is an example of the style that I want to preserve:

```
<img src="/system/images/W1siZiIsIjIwMTUvMDEvMjgvOGpjaXZuYmE1Nl9ldXJvMi5wbmciXSxbInAiLCJ0aHVtYiIsIjExMHgxMTBcdTAwM2UiXV0/euro2.png?sha=4c26963ff920b771" title="Euro2" alt="Euro2" class="img-responsive" style="margin:auto;  width: 30%" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the document that I followed you should install `refinery 3.0.0`
[tutorial](http://www.refinerycms.com/download)